# Use custom renderer on only one Entry control

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms app, I have a custom renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Controls
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (this.Control != null)
            {
                Control.Style = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Style)App.Current.Resources["CustomTextBoxStyle"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I only want to use it on 1 of my `Entry` controls, not all of them. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a custom control MyEntry that inherits from Entry

then in your renderer, specify that it only applies to type MyEntry

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
```